# Epplus cell range numerically

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In EPPlus extension, if I need to set style for a range of cells such as A1 to C1, I will use the following

```
ws.Cells["A1:C1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```

What is the equivalent for this using numbers only?

Comment: Does EPPlus use `Column[]` or `Row[]`?

Answer (score 27):

`Cells` has an overload that will let you do `[FromRow, FromCol, ToRow, ToCol]` like this:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, 3].Style.Font.Bold = true;
```